# I got a file full with hex addresses(char) what's the best way to convert them to unsigned long?

Tags: c, algorithm

I got a file full with hexadecimal addresses, I've managed to parse the file and fetch them
yet I must convert them back to unsigned long, 
what's the best algorithm or fast way to do so considering the file is very long (a few megs) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can start with [`strtoul`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtoul/). It's part of the standard C library, but I include a link here from the C++ reference.

```
char buffer[5];
unsigned long val;
... /* read another 4 valid characters from the file into buffer */
buffer[4] = '\0';
val = strtoul(buffer, NULL, 16);
...
```

Comment: Be sure to catch the errno from strto*, they were implemented _for_ error checking (as opposed to ato*())

Comment: Actually I'm looking for a bit-juggling solution,
is it even attainable ? possible ? 
If so - any hints for the algo ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

a few meg is not big ! You should do this with a script language, e.g. in python

```
out = open("outfile", "w")
try:
    for line in open(myfile, "r"):
        out.write(int(line, 16))
finally:
    out.close()
```

Assuming it is one hex/line. Even if your hex are not consistent, and you need a regex to parse them, it will almost certainly take less than a few seconds on a decent computer. I would not bother with C unless you file is several GB :)

Now, if you need to do this in C, writing the integers is very easy once you have parsed them. What's your problem exactly ? To write to a file ? Or you do have the hex numbers as strings in a file ? In that later case, you could use fscanf with the x format. Or str* functions, as suggested by Jared.

Comment: Did you take two of everything in your medicine cabinet and realize that you could fly, then attribute this super power to Python?

Good, me too.

Comment: I said python like I could have said any other scripting language. The point was that using C for this is not really appropriate, unless he needs to do it within a bigger program (itself in C).

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your input parsed then you might as well just use:

```
unsigned long num;
sscanf(your_hex_string, "%lx", &num);
```